# How to find node using NativeXml : Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, xml-parsing, nativexml

i'm trying to use [NativeXml](http://www.simdesign.nl/xml.html), yes its more simple than xmldocument, but i still cannot find a solution to find node that have multiple name..

```
<item>
  <name>Manggo Salad</name>
  <feature>Good</feature>
  <feature>Excelent</feature>
  <feature>Nice Food</feature>
  <feature>love this</feature>
</item>
```

how to find "feature" ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TXmlNode.FindNodes` takes the NodeName and a `TXmlNodeList/TsdNodeList` which will be filled with all nodes matching this name. If you don't want it to be recursive use `NodesByName`.

Comment: **TXmlNode.FindNodes(string, Tlist)**, how to see the list? ex: see the list at memo

Comment: The list will contain all nodes matching the name. Whatever you want to do with those nodes depends on your needs.

Comment: But i cant find **TXmlNodeList**,  TXmlNode.FindNodes using **Tlist** not **TXmlNodeList**

Comment: In the current version the name is TsdNodeList. As after all it is derived from TList you can pass an instance of it to both methods.

Comment: If you want to stick using a TObjectList descendant **TsdNodeList** is the way to go under NativeXML v4.0.1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another down to earth possible solution:

```
program NodeAccess;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

(*

Assumption

<item>
  <name>Manggo Salad</name>
  <feature>Good</feature>
  <feature>Excelent</feature>
  <feature>Nice Food</feature>
  <feature>love this</feature>
</item>

as XML is stored in "sample.xml" file along with binary executable
of this program.

Purpose
  How to iterate multiple occurence of the "feature" node

*)

uses
  SysUtils,
  NativeXML;

const
  cXMLFileName = 'sample.xml';

var
  i,j: Integer;
  AXMLDoc: TNativeXml;

begin
  try
    Writeln('Sample iterating <',cXMLFileName,'>');
    Writeln;

    AXMLDoc := TNativeXml.Create(nil);

    try
      AXMLDoc.LoadFromFile(cXMLFileName);

      if Assigned(AXMLDoc.Root) then
        with AXMLDoc.Root do
          for i := 0 to NodeCount - 1 do
          begin
            if Nodes[i].Name='feature' then
              for j := 0 to Nodes[i].NodeCount - 1 do
                Writeln('  ',Nodes[i].Name, ' >>> ', Nodes[i].Nodes[j].Value)
          end;
    finally
      AXMLDoc.Free;
    end;

    Writeln;
    Writeln('Hit Return to quit');
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```